# How to correctly dispose of dependencies created by ContainerControlledLifetimeManager in a Prism-Unity-WPF application

Tags: wpf, singleton, unity-container, prism, dispose

I got an application mostly following this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430868%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Here is my bootstrapper class:

```
internal class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    // Wire up the dependencies using Unity container
    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();

        // Register the connection manager
        Container.RegisterType<IConnectionManager, ConnectionManager>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    }

    // Return an instance of the main window
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<Shell>();
    }

    // For WPF, initialising shell is simply setting the data context and showing the main window
    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();

        Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window)this.Shell;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.DataContext =
            ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

The connection manager in the code is registered with `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` which means it will be treated as a singlton.

Now my connection manager is implementing `IDisposable` and I want to know the conventional way to dispose the container in order for it to dispose all related `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`-ed objects.

I started by overriding `OnExit` of the application, but I found that `UnitBootstrapper` doesn't have a dispose method. I can write all the code manually to dispose the container on exit, but I am guessing there must be a formal way to do this kind of usual stuff.

Comment: What do you want to do in the connection manager's `Dispose`? If you really have to do some kind of `disposing` _when your process dies_, you have to implement it manually to happen at an earlier stage.

Comment: I want to dispose some resources I am using in my connection manager before exiting. What do you mean by earlier stage?

Comment: When triggering the closing of the application from an "close-app"-button, for example. But that need to be some remote resources on a database server that won't timeout or something like that, otherwise you don't need to bother yourself, because windows will clean up your process with all memory, port, sockets, handles and everything when your app exits.

Comment: What if the user clicks the windows title bar exit button?

Comment: The shell and then the shell's view model can receive the `Closing` event and react, maybe even rejecting if some transaction is in progress...

Comment: and the connection manager is injected to the view model, so the view or the view model I guess shouldn't be responsible for disposing what they didn't instantiate, right?

Comment: the shell view model doesn't need the connection manager, it needs some kind of connection manager disposer (which can be another interface of the connection manager, of course)

Answer (score 2):

***This question is based on the old-style (Prism 6) Unity Bootstrapper. This answer is compatible with Prism 7 Unity containers.***

An `IUnityContainer` object may be retrieved from the Prism `IContainerProvider` using the a Unity extension method, `GetContainer()`. The `IUnityContainer` can be disposed from the `OnExit` override of an `Application` that inherits from `PrismApplication`:

```
protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnExit(e);
    Container.GetContainer().Dispose(); // must be called to dispose singletons
}
```